# yeoman for codeigniter doesn't set grunt task server

Tags: codeigniter, yeoman, yeoman-generator

i want to use yoeman for codeigniter project. i use generator from this: 
https://github.com/homerjam/generator-codeigniter

but i have a problem, when i run grunt then appear a notification like below:

```
Warning: Task "server" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

how to fixed that warning? and how to make libraries (like : /bower_component) to following codeigniter template rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that generator doesn't include a server task. This makes sense because grunt-contrib-connect, which is the usual server used in Grunt tasks, isn't of any use for a PHP framework like CodeIgniter because it won't execute PHP. You need to use either the PHP development server (in PHP 5.4 and up, use the -S option), or install a proper web server like Apache.